# how to query sub document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

how to query the sub document in sub document.?

how to retreive  the name of the city in commercial document.

```
{
    "_id" : " c2 ",
    "commercial" : {
        " type " : " restaurant ",
        " sale_type " : " sale ",
        " owner_name " : " josi schmit",
        " address " : {
            " street " : " kleine rittergasse ",
            " plot_no " : 4,
            " city " : " frankfurt ",
            " state " : " hessen ",
            " country " : "germany ",
            "postal_code " : 60329,
            "email" : " josi123@gmail.com"
        },
        " total_area " : " 300 sq meters ",
        " sale_price(EUR) " : 100000,
        " features " : {
            " lifts " : 1,
            " heating " : true,
            " parking " : true,
            " kitchen " : true,
            " security_cameras " : true,
            " furniture " : true
        }
    }
}
```

here is my query but i knew i'm wrong please help me.

db.property.find( {"_id": "c2" , "address.city":  "c2"})

Regards
Sreekanth

Comment: try this `db.property.find( {"_id": "c2" , "commercial.address.city": "c2"})`

Answer (score 0):

Actualy there are two methods to do that:

1. `db.property.find ( { "_id": "c2", "commercial.address.city": "c2" }, {"commercial.address.city": true} )`
2. `db.property.find ( { "_id": "c2", "commercial": { "address" : { "city": "c2" }}} )`

The difference in both cases is that in first case mongo will follow the `index` if you have an index `commercial.address.city`, the second one will not, so I sugest you use the first one

Comment: Dear Alexandru I tried both cases but its not showing any output.....there is something missing....

Comment: My bad... didn't put the projection, to be shown,
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/, made the needed modifications

Comment: Dear alexandru db.property.find ( { "_id": " c2 ", "commercial": { "address" : { "$elemmatch" : "city" }}} ) this is what your are expecting

Comment: Dear Alexandru i used both the cases but its not showing any results db.property.find ( { "_id": " c2 ", "commercial.address.city": "c2" }, {"commercial.address.city": true} ). Does spaces matter in monogDB?